# Display multiple rows value of sql server on Asp.Net page using c# ansd asp.net.

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to use all row value of SQL Server database using c# and asp.net.I am explaining my code and db structure below.

> index.aspx:

```
<section class="widget comments">   
<div class="widget-title">4 Comments</div>
<ul>
<li>
 <div class="avatar"><img src="pic/post/1.png" border="0" name="healthawareness" class="commentpostimage positionrelative"></div>
<div class="text">
<div class="author"><a href="#replycommentsection">Reply <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a><span>Callis Ta'eed</span> &nbsp; August 17, 45 minutes ago</div>
<p>Nulla lobortis facilisis eros vitae mollis. Morbi consectetur, tortor ut feugiat rhoncus, nunc augue placerat massa, sit amet laoreet est libero quis nisl. Integer cursus sodales sem eu dapibus. Morbi lobortis eleifend lectus sit amet porttitor. Nam tincidunt congue laoreet.</p>
</div>
<ul>
<li>
<div class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
<div class="text">
<div class="author"><a href="#replycommentsection">Reply <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a><span>Admin</span> &nbsp; August 18, 46 minutes ago</div>
<p>Nulla lobortis facilisis eros vitae mollis. Morbi consectetur, tortor ut feugiat rhoncus, nunc augue placerat massa, sit amet laoreet est libero quis nisl. Integer cursus sodales sem eu dapibus. Morbi lobortis eleifend lectus sit amet porttitor. Nam tincidunt congue laoreet.</p>
</div>
<ul>
<li>
<div class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
<div class="text">
<div class="author"><a href="#replycommentsection">Reply <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a><span>Dr. D R Behera</span> &nbsp; August 18, 47 minutes ago</div>
<p>Nulla lobortis facilisis eros vitae mollis. Morbi consectetur, tortor ut feugiat rhoncus, nunc augue placerat massa, sit amet laoreet est libero quis nisl. Integer cursus sodales sem eu dapibus. Morbi lobortis eleifend lectus sit amet porttitor. Nam tincidunt congue laoreet.</p>
  </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
<div class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
<div class="text">
<div class="author"><a href="#replycommentsection">Reply <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a><span>Richard Delano</span> &nbsp; August 15</div>
<p>Nulla lobortis facilisis eros vitae mollis. Morbi consectetur, tortor ut feugiat rhoncus, nunc augue placerat massa, sit amet laoreet est libero quis nisl. Integer cursus sodales sem eu dapibus. Morbi lobortis eleifend lectus sit amet porttitor. Nam tincidunt congue laoreet.</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

> T_Comments

```
id     name        email                     comments   Created_On   

1      ajay       ajay@gmail.com             hiiii      2015-08-06 16:56:29.117

2      Raj        Raj@gmail.com              hello      2015-08-11 10:59:41.830
```

From the above code the content `i.e-4 comments` should replace with number of records in the database `e.g-2 comments` .The content `i.e-<span>Callis Ta'eed</span>` will be replace with all name field from database.The content `i.e-<p>Nulla lobortis facilisis eros vitae mollis. Morbi consectetur, tortor ut feugiat rhoncus, nunc augue placerat massa, sit amet laoreet est libero quis nisl. Integer cursus sodales sem eu dapibus. Morbi lobortis eleifend lectus sit amet porttitor. Nam tincidunt congue laoreet.</p>` will be replace with comments field and time will be replace by `created on`field of database.In this order all row will repeat.Please help me to do this.

Comment: What did you tried so far ? Show us the code of your attempt.

Comment: I was trying but the design is little bit complicate but you can give me the idea to do this.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois: Let me to know which controller is good to bind single content.

Comment: Is this happening at the loading of the page or with a user action ?

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois:it will happen at loading of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am currently doing for this is :

1 - I fetch the data I need from my database

2 - I use this information to fill a class collection ( in this case `Collection<comments>` )

3 - Then I loop over the items of the collection to create an XML representation of that collection. It makes me able to bind everything i need everywhere I want it.

4 - Then I apply an XSL Transformation on this XML data to get the XHTML code.

5 - Then I send it back and I display it.

In this solution there is no C# controller involved for the create of the HTML code. So if you absolutely want to use C# controller this is not the answer you are looking for :/